# Help with basic shell script. /bin/sh: source: not found

Tags: bash, shell, cron

My cron :

```
45 10 * * * source /home/ThinkCode/Test/hello.sh
```

hello.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "helloworld"
```

The error it emails me :

```
/bin/sh: source: not found
```

What am I doing wrong? It is configuration/environment specific, so Googling didn't help much! Thanks..

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Real `sh` doesn't have `source`, only `.`. Either change the shell in cron to `bash`, or use `.` instead.

Comment: You do this with the line: `SHELL=/bin/bash`

Answer (score 9):

Why are you `source`ing the file from cron. Why not just execute it?