# Activate Anaconda Python environment from makefile

Tags: python, bash, makefile, virtualenv, anaconda

I want to use a makefile to build my project's environment using a makefile and [anaconda/miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html), so I should be able to clone the repo and simply run `make myproject`

```
myproject: build

build:
  @printf "\nBuilding Python Environment\n"
  @conda env create --quiet --force --file environment.yml
  @source /home/vagrant/miniconda/bin/activate myproject
```

If I try this, however, I get the following error

> make: source: Command not found
>
> make: *** [source] Error 127

I have searched for a solution, but [this question/answer([How to source a script in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507810/howto-source-a-script-from-makefile)) suggests that I cannot use `source` from within a makefile.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736146/how-to-use-virtualenv-in-makefile), however, proposes a solution (and received several upvotes) but this doesn't work for me either

> ( \
>       source /home/vagrant/miniconda/bin/activate myproject; \
>
> )
>
> /bin/sh: 2: source: not found
>
> make: *** [source] Error 127

I also tried moving the `source activate` step to a separate bash script, and executing that script from the makefile. That doesn't work, and I assume for the a similar reason, i.e. I am running `source` from within a shell.

I should add that if I run `source activate myproject` from the terminal, it works correctly.

Comment: Read the contents of `/home/vagrant/miniconda/bin/activate`. Note that `source` is a shell built-in, not an executable to invoke, it executes the file's statements in the context of the current shell. Since `make` runs a different copy of shell, you cannot activate a virtualenv from it _in your current shell_, the same way you cannot change your current shell's directory from a makefile.

Comment: So essentially there is no way for me to achieve this with a makefile?

Comment: You can clone a repo, activate an environment in a shell and run a make step (possibly another makefile) _in that invocation of shell_. E.g. `/bin/sh -c "source path/to/activate; make me_a_sandwich"`

Comment: @PhilipO'Brien It would be really interesting to see what approach you picked in the end. I am facing the same limitations.

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem; I wanted to create, or update, a conda environment from a Makefile to be sure my own scripts could use the python from that conda environment.
By default make uses *sh* to execute commands, and *sh* doesn't know *source* (also see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975370/help-with-basic-shell-script-bin-sh-source-not-found)). I simply set the SHELL to bash and ended up with (relevant part only):

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
CONDAROOT = /my/path/to/miniconda2
.
.
install: sometarget
        source $(CONDAROOT)/bin/activate && conda env create -p conda -f environment.yml && source deactivate
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Big thanks for the tip - setting my shell to be the Bash shell was the trick to getting the `source` command to work!

Comment: Also using `&&` seems to be required to get the commands to run within environment.

Comment: that really helps

Answer (score 3):

You should use this, it's functional for me at moment.

```
report.ipynb : merged.ipynb
    ( bash -c "source ${HOME}/anaconda3/bin/activate py27; which -a python; \
        jupyter nbconvert \
        --to notebook \
        --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python2 \
        --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=3000 \
        --execute merged.ipynb \
        --output=$< $<" )
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Essentially the only solution is stated by 9000.  I have a setup shell script inside which I setup the conda environment (source activate python2), then I call the make command.  I experimented with setting up the environment from inside Makefile and no success.

I have this line in my makefile:

```
installpy :
   ./setuppython2.sh && python setup.py install
```

The error messages is:

```
make
./setuppython2.sh && python setup.py install
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-29183.write-test'
```

Essentially, I was able to set up my conda environment to use my local conda that I have write access. But this is not picked up by the make process.  I don't understand why the environment set up in my shell script using 'source' is not visible in the make process; the source command is supposed to change the current shell.  I just want to share this so that other people don't wast time trying to do this. I know autotoools has a way of working with python.  But the make program is probably limited in this respect.

My current solution is a shell script:

### cat py2make.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# the prefix should be change to the target
# of installation or pwd of the build system
PREFIX=/some/path
CONDA_HOME=$PREFIX/anaconda3
PATH=$CONDA_HOME/bin:$PATH
unset PYTHONPATH
export PREFIX CONDA_HOME PATH
source activate python2
make
```

This seems to work well for me.

There were a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736146/how-to-use-virtualenv-in-makefile) for similar situation but it does not seems to work for me:

My modified Makefile segment:

```
installpy :
   ( source activate python2; python setup.py install )
```

Error message after invoking make:

```
make
( source activate python2; python setup.py install )
/bin/sh: line 0: source: activate: file not found
make: *** [installpy] Error 1
```

Not sure where am I wrong.  If anyone has a better solution please share it.